# RestEasy @ValidateRequest is not working

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, nhibernate-validator

```
I am having below configuration for a RestEasy Rest WS 

jaxrs-api-2.3.5.Final.jar,
resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar,
resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar,
hibernate-validator-4.3.2.Final.jar,
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

I have added @ValidateRequest on class(tried on method as well) to validate any request input data before processing the request but i dont know why validation in not being invoked.
```

`@Path(value = "/events")`
`@ValidateRequest`
public class EventRestController  {

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, ACCEPT_HEADER })
public Response get(@QueryParam("componentSerialNumber") @NotNull String componentSerialNumber) {

    System.out.println("powerChangeEvevnt.getComponentSerialNumber()   " +   componentSerialNumber);

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

}

i dont know what i am missing.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on auto scanning of Rest resources and providers solved the issue, validation started working.

just set resteasy.scan parameter value  to  true in web.xml

i had explicitly registered all resources in a subclass extending javax.ws.rs.Application  class but it was not considering HibernateValidator as a validator for validation. i found registering HibernateValidator as a validator quite complex, so just removed this explicitly registered configuration class and enabled Automatically scan.